# Error al filtrar elementos y mostrarlos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando hacer un filtro en javascript para que al escribir en el input solo se muestren en pantalla los items que coincidan y estoy un poco stuck.
Supongo que tiene que ver con la funcion maped() que muestra todos los items pero no consigo continuar.
(Para ello estoy usando la api de Rick y Morty)

Este es mi código:

JavaScript.js:

```
// when the windows is loaded then..:
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {
        apiFetch(1);   
        searchInput()
})

// tag HTML
divResult=document.getElementById("result")  // element in HTML display the info
input = document.getElementById('searchInput');

// DATA WITH API FETCH
const apiFetch = async(page) => {
    let url="https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page="+page; // url + page

    api = await fetch(url);  // fecth

    data = await api.json();  // to json - every data valid

    // console.log(data) result in console

    //when change the page:
    divResult.innerHTML="";

    // resultData is every info
    resultData = data.results;

    maped()
    searchInput()
}

// .map to display every data in HTML
const maped = () => resultData.map(item => {
        // creating a element li
        divItem=document.createElement('div')
        divItem.classList.add('list')

        divItem.innerHTML=`
                        <h3>Name: <strong>${item.name}</strong></h3>
                        <img src='${item.image}'>                                 
        `;
        divResult.appendChild(divItem) 
    }).join('')

// FILTER CHARACTERS
function searchInput(){
    input.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
        const textWrite = e.target.value;

        const character = resultData.filter(result => `${result.name.toLowerCase()}`.includes(textWrite.toLowerCase()))
        console.log(character)

        renderCharacter(character)
    }) 
}

 function renderCharacter(resultData){
        const dataString = maped(resultData.result);
}
```

El filtro funciona bien en la consola ya que al escribir se van filtrando los items correctamente.

Comment: Creo que lo conveniente sería que utilizaras la API para filtrar los personajes por su nombre, puntualmente el endpoint [Characters > Filter characters](https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#filter-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores

1.- La función `map` no reemplaza al `for`, esta función se usa para convertir. Tu tienes 10 elementos originales y lo conviertenes en otros 10 elementos y siempre debe tener un `return` (que tu no lo tienes). Para tu caso es mejor es usar un `for`

2.- Tu función `const maped = () => resultData.map(...` recibe cero argumentos, esta función escrita de otra manera es lo mismo que `function maped(){ }`. Pero tu cuando la llamas ingresas un argumento

```
//                                v----ARGUMENTO
const dataString = maped(resultData.result);
```

3.- Cada vez que llames a `apiFetch` por ejemplo para buscar otra página se llamará a `searchInput()` el cual creará un nuevo evento  `input.addEventListener` es decir, si vas secuencialmente en la página 10 la función filtrar se llamará 10 veces.

Aquí un ejemplo.

```js
let divResult, input,resultData;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {
    apiFetch(1);
    
    //cuando carga el dom, seteamos estas variables, incluido el evento
    divResult=document.getElementById("result");
    input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    
    //el evento debe ser "input" NO "keyup". Además la seteamos aquí para que solo exista un evento
    input.addEventListener("input", searchInput); 
})

// DATA WITH API FETCH
const apiFetch = async(page) => {
    let url="https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page="+page; // url + page

    api = await fetch(url);  // fecth

    data = await api.json();  // to json - every data valid

    resultData = data.results;
    renderCharacter(resultData);
}


function searchInput(e){
  const textWrite = e.target.value;
  const character = resultData.filter(result => result.name.toLowerCase().includes(textWrite.toLowerCase()))
  renderCharacter(character)
}

function renderCharacter(resultData){
  divResult.innerHTML="";
  for(let item of resultData){
    divItem=document.createElement('div');
    divItem.classList.add('list');
    divItem.innerHTML=`
                        <h3>Name: <strong>${item.name}</strong></h3>
                        <img src='${item.image}'>`;
    divResult.appendChild(divItem); 
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="searchInput">
<div id="result"></div>
```